# Can we do performance testing on JMeter tool on API in which PKI(public key infrastructure) is implemented ?if yes How?

Tags: jmeter, pki

I am trying to do concurrent testing for the API in which PKI is implemented. I have already implemented on postman and the response is coming fine but I want to do performance testing of the same API on JMeter.
Can you please suggest the technique?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a possibility to send a [client certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate) with JMeter - you need to convert/add it into a [Java Keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) and point JMeter to this keystore via `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` property and specify the password by providing `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` property, it can be done through *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

If you need to have a separate certificate per thread (virtual user) - you will need to additionally go for [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) and "bind" each thread with the respective certificate alias